# declare table inserted values duplicated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-scripts

I try to get two different table values to insert one declare table but the employee ID is duplicate,

```
DECLARE @WSotable TABLE 
                  (
                      Employee int, 
                      ChargedQty int,
                      ReturnQty int
                  )
```

--insert first table data

```
INSERT INTO @WSotable
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MD_Employee.ID,
        SUM(TR_InvoiceDetails.InvoiceQuantity) AS ChargedQty,
        0 AS ChargedQty
    FROM
        TR_SalesOrderHeader 
    INNER JOIN 
        TR_InvoiceHeader ON TR_InvoiceHeader.SalesOrderID  = TR_SalesOrderHeader.ID 
    INNER JOIN 
        TR_InvoiceDetails ON TR_InvoiceDetails.InvoiceID = TR_InvoiceHeader.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        MD_ItemMaster ON TR_InvoiceDetails.ItemID  =  MD_ItemMaster.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        MD_Supplier ON MD_ItemMaster.SupplierID= MD_Supplier.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        MD_Employee ON TR_SalesOrderHeader.CreatedBy = MD_Employee.ID
    WHERE
        MD_Supplier.ID = 3 
        AND MD_ItemMaster.ID = 572
    GROUP BY
        MD_Employee.ID
```

--insert second table data

```
INSERT INTO @WSotable
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MD_Employee.ID,
        0 AS ChargedQty,
        SUM(TR_SalesReturnDetails.ReturnQuantity) AS ReturnQty
    FROM
        TR_SalesReturnHeader
    INNER JOIN
        TR_SalesReturnDetails ON TR_SalesReturnDetails.SalesReturnID = TR_SalesReturnDetails.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        MD_ItemMaster ON TR_SalesReturnDetails.ItemID  =  MD_ItemMaster.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        MD_Supplier ON MD_ItemMaster.SupplierID= MD_Supplier.ID
    INNER JOIN 
        MD_Employee ON TR_SalesReturnHeader.CreatedBy = MD_Employee.ID
    WHERE
        MD_Supplier.ID = 3 
        AND MD_ItemMaster.ID = 572
    GROUP BY
        MD_Employee.ID
```

Result:

[image]

I need to stop `EmployeeID` duplicates

Comment: Are you using [[tag:sql-server]] or [[tag:mysql]]? You've tagged both here.

Comment: Pick a DBMS, any DBMS, but just one dbms, PREFERABLY the one you are actually using

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? The above code will not run on both...

Comment: Also a query with both a `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` is always flawed. Either the `DISTINCT` is redundant and causing unnecessary overhead, or the `GROUP BY` is wrong (and the needs to be fixed, and the `DISTINCT` removed).

Comment: I remove  DISTINCT but still, ID is  duplicate @Larnu

Comment: Why are you `INSERT`ing the data into a temporary table? Why not just do a `SELECT` with 2 `SUM` functions?

Comment: Leaving aside all the other questions, you are running two separate inserts, so of course you'll get dupes. Perhaps you want your second query to be an upsert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return the data with a final aggregation:

```
select Employee, sum(ChargedQty) ChargedQty, sum(ReturnQty) ReturnQty
from @WSotable
group by Employee
```